# How to determine fields in a table using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is it possible to determine fields available in a table (MySQL DB) pragmatically at runtime using SQLAlchemy or any other python library ? Any help on this would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Reflection could do this.

Reflect the database at once using sqlalchemy

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=someengine)
users_table = meta.tables['users']
addresses_table = meta.tables['addresses']
# fields of address_table
fields = addresses_table.columns.keys()
```

See more information at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/schema.html#reflecting-database-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `SHOW TABLE TABLENAME` and get the columns of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the std DB api specification for python ([pep 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)), namely the description member on cursors, so you do not need SQLAlchemy.

for example for using http://www.pymysql.org/ , **user** is your table

```
import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mysql')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM user")
print cur.description
```